# How to choose optimal size for LVM snapshot for cloning MongoDB?

Tags: lvm, snapshot, mongodb

Yes, I know that my question will look familiar to many of you, but I would like to double check with before I start working on it.
I have read similar question: [Snapshot size in lvm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239319/snapshot-size-in-lvm) , but still one moment is not clear to me.
Shortly:
I need to copy MongoDB from one server to another. MongoDB official documentation proposes to use exactly LVM snaphot for backing up and restoring:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/

Here I started to get confused. MongoDB which I need to copy is 8Tb.
Which size of LVM snapshot should I take If I need to take a snapshot, zip it, copy it to another server, move everything from it to a new LV, and run MongoDB ?

Will it be enough, let's say, 37G or not? Will I get all data inside of that LVM snapshot like they are in original LV? Everywhere I read the same thing at LVM snapshot keeps difference between two logical volumes. Does it mean if I copy such snapshot to another server I will not get all data inside of it?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The easiest way to know it is... to do it. You'll know at the end if it was enough (success) or not (snapshot is full). Don't try this if you are using thin-provisioned LVs though (you have to know if that's the case, it's not the default at all).

Comment: Thank you, A.B!